# Can a virtual switch be depatched?

Tags: openvswitch, vswitch

Is it possible to depatch a virtual switch; And is there any point to doing so on a virtual switch?

Comment: Typically the hypervisor allows you to deactivate/disconnect a NIC... But what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: What do you mean `depatch`? I've never heard that term before.

Comment: I never heard the term either until I was looking at Spiceworks tickets today.  I asked my boss about it, and he said that it means when you disconnect the ports on a switch that you aren't using...if they for instance if there's a switch with a patch panel connected to it, and the patch panel connects to an office wall port with nothing attached, you pull the port from the switch; presumably to save electricity.   I didn't know if doing this in a virtual environment would save memory or processing power.  The virtual switch I started up had 58 ports...